# Display given column information for rows that contain a date column with in a certain range

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to able to support this query:

```
select first_name from 
 employees
where hire_date between x and y;
```

I have create the below procedure with no error.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE pr_show_col_table(
    col      IN VARCHAR2,
    tab      IN VARCHAR2,
    date_col IN VARCHAR2,
    dt2      IN VARCHAR2,
    dt1      IN VARCHAR2)
    IS
--
type typ_ref_cur   IS  ref   CURSOR;
cur typ_ref_cur;
type l_record  IS record (first_name employees.first_name%type);
l_rec l_record;
BEGIN
--
OPEN cur FOR 
  ' Select '|| col || ' from ' || tab || ' where ' || date_col || 
  ' Between TRUNC(:startdt) and TRUNC(:enddt) ' 
  USING dt2, NVL(dt1,dt2+1);
--  
  LOOP
    FETCH cur INTO l_rec;
  EXIT    WHEN cur%notfound;
  dbms_output.put_line('Name is '|| l_rec.first_name);
  END LOOP;
CLOSE cur;
--
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
  dbms_output.put_line
  ('Error at line '||dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace|| chr(10)
    || 'Error Message '||dbms_utility.format_error_STACK);
END pr_show_col_table;
```

/

But when I am trying to run this procedure:

```
BEGIN
  pr_show_col_table (
   'first_name', 
   'employees', 
   'hire_date', 
   to_Date('30-DEC-1995','DD-MON-YYYY'),
   TO_DATE('01-JAN-1995','DD-MON-YYYY'));
END;
```

I am receiving below error:

---

Error at line ORA-06512: at "HR.PR_SHOW_COL_TABLE", line 13

Error Message ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you're passing date values into a varchar parameter. Set the data type of the dt2,dt1  parameters to `DATE` instead of `varchar2`

Comment: Thanks Vance. It is working. How I missed this point :( Thanks